# How to data drive coded ui tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tdd, coded-ui-tests

I am comfortable with recording Coded UI tests using the VS2010 Ultimate.

The problem I am running into is that some of the UI controls being tested in the Silverlight app that we have built require data that is machine specific.

If I run the tests on my machine they run great. However, my team mates also have to run the same tests on their own machines. Problem is that the Coded UI tests are recorded with my machine name as an input setting to certain text boxes in the application under test. Unless my team mates re-record the same test with their own machine names, those tests will fail.

After some digging I saw that you can associate a CSV, EXCEL, a database, or XML file to drive your coded ui tests. However all examples on MSDN and elsewhere only show pre-configured answer files, and most of them are in CSV format.

What goes on in the answer file, and how can I create one of my own in XML format to drive the values being inputted into the text-boxes when the coded ui test replays?

Any links and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Not a fan of CodedUI.

Link1 - [Creating a data-driven CodedUI test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx)

It should be possible to use record-n-replay to generate the CodedUI test. Then make the modifications listed above to drive it with inputs from an input-set.

However I'm not sure if re-recording the test would obliterate your modifications... You'd have to try this out and see. If you need this I'd advise using CodedUI in scripting mode (instead of record-n-replay).

Comment: Re-recording the Coded UI tests won't obliterate the XML answer files. The content of those files is stored in the `TestContext.DataRow` object so if you re-record the test you just have to modify the test code to use the variables stored in it.

Comment: Also what I didn't know was the format of the XML files. By trial and error i figured a generic structure: `<TestDefinition><TestRun><variable1/><variable2/><variable3/></TestRun></TestDefinition>`. Seems the coded UI test data source builder looks for an XML file and will allow you to select the `<TestRun/>` tag as the source of the data. The only thing that really bothers me is why or how to embed entire objects, rather than single value variables in the `<TestRun>` tag. I mean I can always delimit stuff inside a string via a pipe `|`, but embedding a full object would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the business logic from the UI and you don't have the problem with any functionality/behavior testing of the UI bits. You will then have the data issues solved. As for testing the UI bits, there are a couple of ways of handling this. One relatively simple method is to bootstrap an IOC container with mocks and setting up UI tests on top of the mocked data.

If you want to get into more automated UAT testing, there are tools for that. Not sure about Silverlight/WPF per se (as I don't spend a huge time in either due to moving all business logic out of the UI bits), but I would imagine there has to be one.

Comment: Separating business logic from UI is called a unit test, where a developer would typically test the utilization of a MVC or MVVM type of pattern. I am doing integration testing where entire Workflows are being tested across multiple system boundaries. Mocks dont cut it because these are system tests from which the software would get it's acceptance and compliance statements.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my mind. I would give you credit for the fact that at least you know the theory behind testing, although the first two lower levels of testing. Any input is positive input even if it doesn't directly solve the problem, which after a long night of screwing around I figured out how to do myself.

Comment: The integration testing can be UAT or it can be coded using a unit test suite. I generally end up with two libraries in my solutions: AssemblyName.Test.Integration and AssemblyName.Test.Unit. Both use MSTest, as an example, but one exercises the stack. Neither exercise the UI, because it is an extremely thin layer with no logic. Following this principle, testing UI is UAT, not integration. And, there are suites for automating parts of UI. I imagine you could also use them for integration, if needed.

Comment: The important part is making sure there is no business logic in the UI. I worked once on a smart client application and they argued the logic had to be in the smart client. True, but not in the freaking .exe file. You can still have a smart client that has libraries. Leave the UI bits clean and have them focus on displaying data and interacting with the user. When you are strict about this, you can easily code integration tests. Potential gotcha: you need a consistent set of data for your tests. I, personally, like lab management in VS team now, but I have done it otherwise in the past.

Comment: You are definetelly correct. However, the scenarios I work with are a bit more sophisticated. An example: Component 1 sends data to component two, where both components reside in two different machines. While component two accepts the data, it also performs data processing operations on it and modifies it according to business rules. The sending of data through component 1 is done via a Coded UI test, where the test interacts with the user interface of the sender. The test also verifies on how the data is processed by component two by retrieving the data from SQL and verifying its contents.

Comment: In the example above, component 1 is what the pre-recorded UI test interacts with physically. Because each tester can have different setting as far as the configuration of both component one and two, the playback of the test execution steps must also be able to use a supplied answer file, preferably in XML format. The answer file would have the settings for each input field used by component one, connection string to database of component two, etc... I am not testing the app at a unit level since its architecture is prohibitive of that due to 3rd party pre-compiled components used in the build